# Display models that includes certain values (basic search)

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I must start by saying that I am VERY new to Django (Python I know :) ).

Let me show you what I have so far and then I'll get into the issue.

The `model`:

```
class Machine(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, primary_key=True)
    user = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    mail = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    datetime = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True, default="")
    licenses = models.CharField(max_length=10000, blank=True, null=True, default="")
```

The `view`:

```
def home(request):
    ...
    return render_to_response("inventory/home.html", {'machines': Machine.objects.all()})
```

and here is part of my `HTML`:

```
<fieldset class="module aligned ">
    <div class="form-row field-name">
        <div>
            <label class="required" for="id_name">License:</label>
            <input class="vTextField" id="id_license" maxlength="255" name="license" type="text" value="">
        </div>
    </div>
</fieldset>


<div class=results>
    <table width="100%" border="1" cellpadding="4"  cellspacing="0" bordercolor="#eeeeee">
        <tr bgcolor='WhiteSmoke' style="color: 'black'">
            <td><input type="checkbox" id="action-toggle" style="display: inline-block;"></td>
            <td>Name</td>
            <td>User</td>
            <td>Mail</td>
            <td>Registration date</td>
            <td>Registered licenses</td>
        </tr>

        {% for machine in machines %}
            {% if machine.datetime %}
        <tr bgcolor='CCFF66'>
            {% else %}
        <tr bgcolor='FF6666'>
            {% endif %}

            <td class="action-checkbox">
                <input class="action-select" name="_selected_action" type="checkbox" value="{{machine.name}}">
            </td>
            <td>{{ machine.name }}</td>
            <td>{{ machine.user }}</td>
            <td>{{ machine.mail }}</td>
            <td>{{ machine.datetime|default:"N/A" }}</td>
            <td>{{ machine.licenses|default:"N/A"|truncatewords:"5" }}</td>

        </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    </table>
</div>
```

Here is the result:
[image]

As you can see above, currently **all** items (called machines) are being displayed but I would like to present **only the machines with a certain license text**.

So **as soon as** user starts typing into "license search field" only the items with that license would show up (I hope I have managed to explain the issue well enough).

At this point I don't really know where to start looking! I check some django tutorial but they don't get into stuff maybe this advanced!

Comment: Are you looking for a client side or a server side search?

Comment: @anuragal the easiest way at this point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can perform the search at server side, for this follow steps

1. Put the `License` search box into a HTML form and add a submit button next to it.
2. On submit call a view which will get the value entered in `license' text box.
3. Perform a filter on table
4. return the results.

The first part of HTML will be changed to -

```
<fieldset class="module aligned ">
    <div class="form-row field-name">
        <div>
            <form method="post">
                <label class="required" for="id_name">License:</label>
                <input class="vTextField" id="id_license" maxlength="255" name="license" type="text" value="">
                <button type="submit">Search</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</fieldset>
```

And view will look something like this -

```
def home(request):
    ...
    if request.POST:
        license_text = request.POST.get('license', '')
        machines = Machine.objects.filter(licenses__istartswith=license_text) #or you can use __in operator
    else:
        machines: Machine.objects.all()

    return render_to_response("inventory/home.html", {'machines': machines})
```

No other changes are required. Code not tested but it should work

Comment: Let me test your solution :)

Comment: @theAlse: let me cite your words: 'So as soon as user starts typing into "license search field"'
So in my understanding you are looking for a more complex search that involves a solution that uses AJAX, because you want to execute a new search for every letter that is entered into the search form. 

Is this what you are after?

Comment: @Dr.Elch, yes! exactly!

Comment: @theAlse - Search while you type will be complex for a person who is new to Django. You can take this as a starting point and then try to learn ajax and improve this code.

Comment: @anuragal, thanks for your reply and I am accepting it as the answer!